# Difference between two Z-values extracted using "Extract -Z values" tool in QGIS 3

Tags: vector, extract, z-value, qgis-3

When I run Extract-Z tool (vector geometry) and select Q3, I get two values for each object:

[image: Attribute Table]

In many cases, the two values are almost identical, but in some, they differ quite a bit. There is no explanation in the docs for these two values.

Can anybody explain what the difference is?

Comment: What is geometry type of the layer? Point, line or polygon?

Comment: It is a polygon layer

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer**: `Q3` in the field names is just a output column prefix you specified. So, `Q3first` is z-value of the first point of the line/polygon. `Q3q3` is the third quartile of the all z values of points of the line/polygon.

---

**CASE 1**: Point Layer

There is one Z value for each point. Therefore, all min, max, q1, q3, etc. are the same.

**CASE 2**: Line or Polygon Layer

Lines and polygons are defined at least 2 and 3 points, respectively. For example, for the line in the image, which point's z value should QGIS use?

Image 1: Sample line having z-value.
[image]

QGIS offers different options:

- First: Use z value of the first point as z value of the line/polygon. (`10`)
- Last: Use z value of the last point. (`20`)
- Minimum, Maximum, Sum, Mean, Median, etc. are quite obvious.
- Q1: Use first quartile of the all z values of points of the line/polygon. (`12.5`)
- Q3: Use third quartile. (`17.5`)

Image 2: Quartiles for z value's of the sample line
[image]

Image 3: Different QGIS options for "[Extract Z Values](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#extract-z-values)" tool and the result
[image]

Comment: Cok sagolun Kadir, so it was a mistake of mine... Thanks!

Comment: Great answer, indeed!