# Selecting features by quartiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, select

I have a polygon layer. I drew a boxplot calculated from field `area` in the layer.

How can I select the features whose `area` value is within interquartile range (25%-75%)?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two expression functions (`q1` and `q3`) which return %25 and %75 quartiles. You can use both in `Select Features by Expression` tool.

> Docs:
> `q1`: Returns the calculated first quartile from a field or expression.
> `q3`: Returns the calculated third quartile from a field or expression.

```
$area > q1( $area ) and $area < q3( $area )
```

Different combinations can also be used.

Comment: Check also this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/353885/29431